# ActiveModelSerializer requires functions in right order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Working on front-end and json responses on RoR backend, I'm trying to set up serializers to avoid code cluttering with `:only => []` and so on.

What I find out, is that in serializer with associations we can't use name of class, which is not yet initialized.

```
class AuthorOnlySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :real_name, :wiki_link
end

class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :authors, serializer: AuthorOnlySerializer
  attributes :id, :title, :isbn, :publish_year, :detail
end
```

Such code works properly, but if I switch these classes (having them in one file now) (UPD for understanding: what I mean by switching is putting BookSerializer in front of AuthorOnlySerializer in file), I'm getting

```
uninitialized constant BookSerializer::AuthorOnlySerializer
```

Is there any way to avoid these problem and to be able to put them in any order? I've tried supplying symbol instead of class into serializer option, but then comes

```
undefined method `new' for :AuthorOnlySerializer:Symbol
```

, so it doesn't support anything but classes there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: when exactly does this error happen? i did not understand this part.

Comment: Error happens, when I'm trying to call something, which requires work of serializer. In this example, I was trying to call books.json , which is processed through respond_with(@books). UPD for understanding: what I mean by switching is putting BookSerializer in front of AuthorOnlySerializer in file